# App does not start on VS 2017 Xamarin Emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

A simple xamarin.android method perfectly worked on VS 2015. Now with the new VS 2017 version the emulator starts, but keeps black and the related app is not working and showing an ongoing message "Android is starting - optimizing app 1 of 1".

1. I checked with the Android SDK manager the path for android-sdk, which seems to be ok (Android API 23, 25 and 26 SDK Platforms are installed).
2. I installed the Intel HAXM.
3. I checked the Hyper-V Emulator for Windows 10 Pro
   without any effects on the start or debug of the app.

Xamarin Diagnostics:

```
[I:]:                     Found Xamarin.Android 7.3.99.108
[I:sdk]:                  Runtime path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
[I:sdk]:                  Framework path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_399f2be8\Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_399f2be8\Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_399f2be8\Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
[I:]:                     Found Android SDK. API levels: 19, 21, 22, 23, 25
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\Stephan\.android\avd'
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 4 devices
[W:]:                     Adb connection refused
[I:]:                     Starting Adb server (adb start-server)
[I:]:                     Adb start-server operation completed
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
```

Here the related Build log:

```
1>Starting deploy VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone ...
1>Starting emulator VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone ...
1>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone -prop monodroid.avdname=VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone
1>emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
1>emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
1>Emulator VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone is running.
1>Waiting for emulator to be ready...
1>...
1>...
1>...
1>...
1>Emulator is not ready to be used.
1>Deploy failed on VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas .. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try on a physical device? What about trying [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)? The Emulators in the Android SDK are known to be quite poor performance-wise

Comment: You are using `VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone`, which doesn't leveraging HAXM and runs also very slowly, please change to certain emulator like `VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone` or `VisualStudio_android-23_x64_phone`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now deinstalling the HAXM and launching a VS Android Emulator (vs_emulator 5" KitKat 4.4 API 19) on a Windows 10 Pro system with Hyper-V.